# How to delete the last character of a file

Tags: batch-file, del

I use this batch files to create a list of files

```
@echo off
(for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir/b/a-d *.tex') do   echo %%a,)>liste.dat
```

the result is like this

```
file1.tex,
file2.tex,
file3.tex,
...
lastfile.tex,
```

how do I delete the last comma?

Comment: why echo %%a, is used ? is there any need, i believe you could use echo %%a instead , i would love to know if there is a reason ,other wise removing comma after the echo %%a will do the needful

Comment: @prudviraj: perhaps to insert a comma in all lines? The OP wants to "delete **the last** comma" only!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "comma="
< NUL (
for %%a in (*.tex) do (
   set /P "=!comma!%%a"
   set comma=,^
%Empty line%
)
echo/
) > liste.dat
```

**EDIT**: *Reply to a comment*

Ops! When I was developing this code I just displayed the output in the screen, where it looks correct:

```
C:\> test.bat
One.tex,
Three.tex,
Two.tex
```

Even if the output is sent to a file and the file is displayed in the screen, the output looks correct:

```
C:\> test.bat > output.txt

C:\> type output.txt
One.tex,
Three.tex,
Two.tex
```

However, the character inserted after each comma is just a LF so if this file is open with Notepad, the LF's are *not* converted to "end of lines"; just cmd.exe *screen* output converts LF to CR+LF pair (*"cooked output"* instead of *"raw output"*).

The way to fix this detail is inserting a complete CR+LF pair after each comma:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F %%a in ('copy /Z "%~F0" NUL') do set "CR=%%a"

set "comma="
< NUL (
for %%a in (*.tex) do (
   set /P "=!comma!%%a"
   set comma=,!CR!^
%Empty line%
)
echo/
) > liste.dat
```

Comment: The `%Empty line%` is intended to append a new-line char. to `comma`, right?

Comment: Did I misunderstand the intended output? The output example shows one entry on each line with a comma. Yours is all on one line.

Comment: @Aacini, I totally forgot that Notepad did that with Line Feeds.  Weird thing is I ran into that same problem two days ago with a batch file I downloaded the other day.  I opened it in notepad and said WTF. Then opened it in Notepad++ and noticed the LF only.  Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 3):

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
SET "in="
(
for %%a in (*.tex) do (
    IF "!in!"=="" (
        set in=%%a
    ) ELSE (
        echo !in!,
        set in=%%a
    )
)
echo !in!
)>liste.dat
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272/274165), because they don't teach the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't know how many lines/files there will be. So you'll have to use two loops the way your code is written. One to count the lines and one to perform the operations. It's way easier to have a different handling for the first line instead of the last one. So how about this:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
SET /a i=0
(for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b/a-d *.tex') do (
    IF !i!==1 (
        echo ,%%a
    ) ELSE (
        ECHO %%a
        SET /a i=1
    )
)
)>liste.txt
```

This will generate something like this:

```
file1.tex
,file2.tex
,file3.tex
...
,lastfile.tex
```

This seems equivalent to your desired output. If you actually want to have `,` at the end of the lines instead of at the beginning of the next one, tell me and I'll update the code but it'll be quite ugly.